# Node.js connection with MongoDB not throwing error message and not creating collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, windows, command-line-interface

So I'm using Node.js to connect to MongoDB, and every time I run my JS file via CMD, typing "node index.js", my code that is supposed to CreateCollection() or InsertOne() in the MongoDB cloud doesn't throw any errors, and my collection or document is not created.

NPM version: 9.5.0
Node version: 18.15.0
Mongo driver version: 5.1.0

My project folder looks like:

> node_modules
> index.js
> package.JSON
> package-lock.JSON

My code inside index.js document looks like:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = "mongodb+srv://username:<Password>@cluster0.wdj4kyi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(url);

client.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  const database = client.db('mydatabase');

  database.createCollection('mycollection', (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Collection created!');
    client.close();
  });
});
```

Yes, I changed "Username" and "Password" from the url to my own credentials;
After some research, I found that not throwing any errors could mean that the collection is already created or the user doesn't have the right permission, but none of them are True. I've guaranteed to my user the permission to read and write any database in the MongoDB cloud.

I have tried to reinstall the packages. I even formatted my computer thinking that there was a corrupted file or something.
I have created another account in MongoDB Cloud, thinking that there was a miss configuration in mongo;
I also tried different sintaxes like:

```
// const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient
// const url = "mongodb+srv://Username:<Password>@cluster0.wdj4kyi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

// mongodb.connect(url,(error,base)=\>{
//     if(error)throw error;
//     const dbo = base.db("info")
//     const obj = {Name:"Pedro",Age:"23"}
//     const collec = dbo.collection("Infocollection").insertOne(obj,(error,result)=\>{
//         if(error)throw error
//         console.log("Inserted")
//         base.close()
//     })
// })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code inside `try-catch` block to handle and diagnose errors like so:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const url = "mongodb+srv://username:<Password>@cluster0.wdj4kyi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(url);

client.connect(async (err) => {
  try {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }

    const database = client.db('mydatabase');

    const result = await database.createCollection('mycollection');
    console.log('Collection created!', result);

    const obj = { Name: 'Pedro', Age: '23' };
    const collection = database.collection('Infocollection');
    const insertResult = await collection.insertOne(obj);
    console.log('Document inserted!', insertResult);

    client.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: It does the same. No errors and no collection.